# Disable Tomboy System Tray

Tags: tomboy

First of all, I don't use indicator applet, but I suppose that the icon/process managing Tomboy is the same for both indicator applet and system tray.

I want only notificaitons in my system tray (apps have a different dwelling!). How do I, if at all possible, force Tomboy to always start in the "search all notes" mode WITHOUT showing a system tray icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some checking around in gconf, and sadly this is not possible in the standard version. You could add the unsupported [tomboy ppa](https://launchpad.net/~tomboy-packagers/+archive/development) and use the latest version (which has no indicator applet) and then disable the icon in gconf (/apps/tomboy/enable_tray_icon).

[image: gconf-editor]
*This setting would normally work, but only in the latest version of tomboy*

I would also like to suggest that you report a wishlist bug on indicator applet to allow hiding *(I would, but I know I would be ignored :P)*.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted! I actually had that version already due to indicator applet related bugs! (Why would you be ignored?)

Comment: Lol I won't go into why I would be ignored, but I'm almost certain I would be :)

Comment: It would be great if you would note which version number adds this feature (or even the first version you know of that has this feature, even if you're not sure that's the version that added it). That way, people can just check their version number instead of having to look up the PPA. Thanks! :)

Comment: I have the standard version, so I really can't tell without upgrading again.